# What do you call tooltips that stay on hover?

Tags: guidelines, semantics

I am trying to create a style guide and have two types of tooltips and am having a hard time finding a semantic naming for them.

Type 1 - Stays if you hover over the tooltip, so that you can include links. This type is to include information or explanation on features (About 1 or 2 paragraph). [Example](http://gyazo.com/61143be8702c56081a7cd35aa1dbc3d6)

Type 2 - Disappears as soon as you hover out of the help icon. This type if generally to include quick short information (a few words). [Example](http://gyazo.com/7454427fb4870784c7c698aba6e1e740)

Do you have any ideas? I don't seem to be able to find it even referencing Bootstrap or Material Design.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the difference between the two types? They both show something when you hover over and disappear when off focus. Can you try to explain the difference a bit better?

Comment: My apologies. 

I refer specifically to [Facebook Analytics Demo](https://www.facebook.com/analytics/776816812461629/?since=1470441600000&until=1472428800000&section=overview)

Type 1 is used specifically to explain features (so longer, richer) - Example https://gyazo.com/61143be8702c56081a7cd35aa1dbc3d6
Type 2 is used to provide hints on what you are about to click or full value of abbreviations. Example https://gyazo.com/7454427fb4870784c7c698aba6e1e740

Comment: Great, you should edit to include these examples into your original question, so that others don't have the same confusion.

Comment: yada-yada-sticky

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap calls them Popovers:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: That might be right, but I think that popover occurs only when you click something (so it pops up).

Comment: If you refer to bootstrap specifically, according to the documentation you can change the trigger to one of these _click | hover | focus | manual_

Comment: That make sense. We have another component that pop up after you click on something to show a menu, which we call popover. So I guess maybe we should differentiate it with its triggers and use.

Like **Popover - Tooltip on Click**

Comment: In the design system I'm currently working on I do the same as bootstrap: the component name is determined by its appeareance (speack HTML and CSS) and it's interactions, the trigger is usually just an option the designer can specify. But I've worked on projects where they separated the componentens just like you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Material-UI call them interactive tooltips:
https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#interactive

(I would post it as a comment, but I don't have enough points)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make them the same component and add a delay when hiding them. So when you hover the thing that brings the tooltip up, when hovering out you delay hiding the tooltip by, say 0.5 seconds. If in that time the user moved the cursor to be on the tooltip, you keep it open, allowing them to click the link.

Possibly the delay can be even shorter, see what works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're describing different *behaviors* of tooltips, not different types of components. Why not differentiate them as such. You would probably want to define what the preferred default tooltip behavior is and differentiate the other behavior as an option.